# Expose the edit history of moderator-edited comments to other moderators

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, edits, moderator-tools

I was recently notified that another moderator on the site had suspended a specific user. I followed this to the source, but found some edited comments. My colleague had removed the offending parts from the comments. While I know that the suspension was justified in this case based on other information, I find it a bit problematic that such moderator actions can't be followed easily.

Moderators are all CCed on suspensions, this helps to keep informed about problematic stuff that happened on the site, and serves as a way to check the actions of an individual moderator. But this doesn't really work when comments are edited, as we can't see the old versions without help from an SE employee.

This is one reason why I personally never edit comments in such a way, but instead just remove them entirely. This sometimes removes valid information as well, so it is not without drawbacks.

While this isn't needed very often, I think it would be useful if moderator could see the edit history of comments edited by moderators. This would bring editing comments on the same level of transparency as other moderator actions.

Comment: As moderator, I would like to be able to see any edits made to comments, not just for the ones edited by moderators, especially if the comment gets flagged. If a user writes something offensive and then edits it off, I would like to be able to see that.

Comment: Yeah, it's frustrating that we mods can't see that edit history.  A workaround I try to follow for egregious cases (really offensive, *but* there's some reason not to just delete wholesale) is to record the pre-edit version in an annotation or mod chatroom.  But that requires extra work and depends on remembering to do so -- better than nothing, but not a fix.

Comment: do you consider this already solved?

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not a mod anymore, so I can't see with mod permissions. I think it is resolved, but I'm not exactly sure what mods can see now in this regard.

Answer (score 8):

This feature has been implemented since October 2016 for comments edited after October 2012. Moderators can click the pencil icon on the edited comment to see its comment history.

As of January 2022, it looks like this (moderator's name is manually redacted on here)

[image]